# My UK visa application status

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I have applied for a visa on 12th July and I have opted for SMS notifications. First day I got an SMS from VFS team stating application forwarded to Embassy. Today is the 10th working day and I have not received any further updated SMS from VFS team about the application status.

Answer (score 6):

The SMS Notification service is one of the premium services offered in some locations. It sends an SMS advisory each time a relevant, **notifiable** event occurs in Proviso (the visa application software).

There are about two triggers: receipt of application and decision reached. Sometimes there is a third asking you to schedule an interview (that's a bad thing). And sometimes settlement applicants have more. There are no intermediate steps like '1/3 of the way done' or 'yours is next' or 'just a little bit more'.

You signed up for the service and got the first SMS. You are presumably now waiting for the SMS telling you that a decision has been made and to collect your stuff from the VFS.

Based upon all of that plus what you wrote, your application is currently *pending* and that's the extent of what you will learn about it barring a Parliamentary enquiry (which resets your turn-around clock).

Extra: You used the 'airlines' tag and it might mean you are coming up to a flight date. If that's the case note that purchasing tickets in advance of a visa decision is ill-advised. This is because the UK government does not see visa applications as a formality.  So the bottom line is that you have to brass it out and cancel your flights if necessary.

Comment: I like the idea of starting a parliamentary enquiry about one’s visa application status. I’m sure it can only affect the application in a positive way especially concerning the decision time ;-)

Comment: @Jan good point! I will update this answer